# Get from MySQL database and count specific rows

Tags: mysql

I building a shopping cart for small restaurant. I have database for items

```
item_id
item_name
item_price1 (normal)
item_price2 (with discount)
item_category
```

And shopping cart MySQL

```
shoping_card_id
shoping_card_session
shoping_card_item (item_id)
shoping_card_quantity
```

and I call my shopping cart with this query

```
$shoping_card_session = $_SESSION['ime'];
$rezultat = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM shop_kosarica WHERE shoping_card_session='$shoping_card_session' AND shoping_card_quantity<>0 ORDER BY shoping_card_id ASC");
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($rezultat);
if ($num_results==0){
    echo "<h2><strong>Card is empty</strong></h2><br><br>";
}else{
    while ($redak = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat)){
        $item_id = $redak['shoping_card_item'];
        $rezultat_artikal = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM shop_artikal WHERE item_id='$item_id'");
        $redak_artikal = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat_artikal);
.....some code...
}
```

But now client wants query to automatically calculate, if there are 3 or more items with item_category 6, and on that item calculate discount on price -15%. So to show price from field item_price2 insted of item_price1. (I already calculate discount on price and put it in field item_price2). Any idea?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Here is a edit, I insert php code for executing query.

Comment: I would not have a second field for discount price.  This sounds like some separate cart/discounting logic that needs to be done. Having a second field for that price would be a very odd way to do this. MOre complex carts with various discounting scenarios often have additional table(s) to deal with discounting/bundling logic.

Comment: that is card for taxi pizza, no online payment or something like that, just get to pizzeria in e-mail and they call castumer to confirm. item go in cart and when he click order go on e-mail to pizzeria.